# SciFi novel read around 1990s-2000s about time travel with drugs

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, drug

I read this book in France, around 1990s, or early 2000s maybe. It looked new so it may have been written recently. I read it in french, but I cannot tell if it was translated from a foreign language...

I was a teenager at this time but the book was quite hard to read so likely not a young adult book.

At some point in the future, they know a drug that gives the ability to time travel *in their mind, or dreams*. But it was risky, because if they took too much of it, they could stay there for ever and the body might stay braindead.

A scientist of the future uses some drug to time travel and he goes in the mind of a business executive of the past (maybe the 1980s) to investigate a conspiracy in a big company.

My memory is very blurred, it was book hard to read because of time loops (like in the Groundhog Day movie) he lives some situations several times and modifies some details.

Comment: Please try to add anything that may help identification. When roughly was it written? What time period was it set in? What language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question.

Comment: The description vaguely reminds me of Philip K. Dick's [Ubik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubik), but with what little info you have given, this is kind of a long shot.

Comment: @Paulie_D, I edited and added as much info as I can.

Comment: I second @ComicSansMS comment - this is likely a Philip K. Dick story.  His stories were hard to read, and frequently used drugs to achieve effects like apparent time travel, role-play, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It does sound a bit like [Now wait for last year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Now_Wait_for_Last_Year) by P.K. Dick- main character is an organ transplant donor that after taking a drug (apparently originally developed as a chemical weapon) is able to travel back in time and see alternate historylines

Comment: I will check on that.